# Calcululate the limit of a function of several variables by using the squeeze theorem.

Tags: calculus

This is the function

$$\lim_{(x,y )\to (7,3)}(x^2-49)\cos\left(\frac{349}{(x-7)^2+(y-3)^2}\right)$$

I can figure out the ones at it approaches 0, but I can’t figure it out whe it approaches any other number.

Comment: Change variables $x'=x-7$, $y'=y-3$ and you have a limit that approaches $(0,0)$.

Comment: "I can figure out the ones at it approaches 0, but I can’t figure it out whe it approaches any other number." What does this mean?

Answer (score 2):

$\cos(f(x,y))$ is a  bounded function so it just doesn't matter. We know $-1\leq \cos(f(x,y))\leq 1$ hence the required limit is $0$.

Comment: Any other number like what

Comment: Sorry, that was a comment for @MMTC.

Comment: okay no problem.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternate answer, note that most of the techniques introduced in a multivariable calculus course involve multivariate limits of the form
$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} f(x,y).$$

These techniques generalize by using to change of coordinates $u=x-a$ and $v=y-b$ to evaluate limits $(x,y) \to (a,b)$:

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (a,b)} f(x,y) = \lim_{(u,v) \to (0,0)} f(u+a, v+b).$$

For your problem, we let $u= x-7$ and $v=y+3$, giving

\begin{align*}&\lim_{(x,y )\to (7,3)}(x^2-49)\cos\left(\frac{349}{(x-7)^2+(y-3)^2}\right)\\ 
&= \lim_{(u,v) \to (0,0)} ((u+7)^2 - 49) \cos \left( \frac{349}{(u+7-7)^2 + (v+3-3)^2}   \right) \\
&= \lim_{(u,v) \to (0,0)} (u^2 + 14u) \cos \left( \frac{349}{u^2 + v^2} \right).
\end{align*}

From here, we note that $-1 \leq \cos \left( \frac{349}{u^2 + v^2} \right) \leq 1$ for all $u$ and $v$. Thus
\begin{align*}
\lim_{(u,v) \to (0,0)} (u^2 + 14u) \cdot(-1) &\leq \lim_{(u,v) \to (0,0)} (u^2 + 14u) \cos \left( \frac{349}{u^2 + v^2} \right) \leq \lim_{(u,v) \to (0,0)} (u^2 + 14u)\cdot 1 \\
0 &\leq \lim_{(u,v) \to (0,0)} (u^2 + 14u) \cos \left( \frac{349}{u^2 + v^2} \right) \leq 0
\end{align*}

and we conclude by the squeeze theorem that
$$\lim_{(u,v) \to (0,0)} (u^2 + 14u) \cos \left( \frac{349}{u^2 + v^2} \right) =0 $$
and so 
$$\lim_{(x,y )\to (7,3)}(x^2-49)\cos\left(\frac{349}{(x-7)^2+(y-3)^2}\right) =0.$$